# Count of child rows for selected parent row in RadGridView

Tags: wpf, vb.net, radgridview

I'd like to get a count of child rows for a selected parent in a radgridview that supports extended selection.  This code gets me the number of parent rows selected:

```
Dim nbrParentSelected As Integer = myGrid.SelectedItems.Count
```

This code gets me the number of child rows for a selected parent but only in the immediate window.  If I put this in code, I get a late binding disallowed error.

```
myGrid.SelectedItems(0).thePropertyCollection.Count
```

How do I get this count using code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`Dim nbrParentSelected As Integer = myGrid.RowCount - 2
MsgBox(nbrParentSelected)`

This is because the Rows count in DataGridView start from *zero* and since you enabled editing mode so your last row count should be - 1 of total row count if you want to count in from 1 and plus -1 as there is an extra Row which you do not need to be counted...

> I guess this is what you needed. Or at least you will get some idea.

Comment: Oh! Now I saw you asked about radgridview sorry. I don't know about it so you can ignore the answer...

Answer (score 0):

This code gives me what I need.

```
        Dim selectedRow = DirectCast(myGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myGrid.SelectedItem), GridViewRow)
    Dim childCount = selectedRow.ChildrenOfType(Of GridViewRow)().Count
```

Found in coding sample [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/get-child-selected-items).

Edited to add:  I can get the count of children by using the child collection.

```
   chosenParent = TryCast(myGrid.SelectedItems(i), parentCollection)

   countOfChildren = chosenParent.childrenCollection.Count
```

And I can do this without expanding the parent row first.